# What do you call the date you stop doing something?

Tags: adjectives

What do you call the day or date you stop doing something? Something like graduation, what is the formal description of that date?

Comment: "Graduation date".

Comment: Isn't there anything else besides graduation date? @HotLicks

Comment: Whatever it is that you are stopping doing, you could think of it as a beginning: it's "the first day of the rest of your life".

Comment: @HotLicks You mean if on Thursday I stop picking my nose in public, that is called graduation date?

Comment: Note that Alcoholics Anonymous likely has a term for the date of one's last drink.

Comment: **date of last activity**, usually seen in bank account statements, though.

Comment: In smoking-related terms, informally "**quit day**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synonyms for **ultimate** meaning #2

> following all others of the same kind in order or time

at M-W are:

> bottommost, closing, concluding, final, hindmost, lag, latest, latter, rearmost, terminal, terminating, last.

Though not specific to a date, perhaps one will suit?